# No match for 'operator<<' in std::cout

Tags: c++, cout

I am developing gsoap web service where I am retrieving vectors of objects in return of a query. I have two ways to do it: first by simple loop and by iterator. None of them working.

The error is:

> error: no match for `'operator<<'` in `'std::cout
>   mPer.MultiplePersons::info.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::at<PersonInfo, std::allocator<PersonInfo> >(((std::vector<PersonInfo>::size_type)i))'`

```
MultiplePersons mPer; // Multiple Person is a class, containing vector<PersonInfo> info
std::vector<PersonInfo>info; // PersonInfo is class having attributes Name, sex, etc.
std::vector<PersonInfo>::iterator it;

cout << "First Name: \t";
cin >> firstname;
if (p.idenGetFirstName(firstname, &mPer) == SOAP_OK) {
    // for (int i = 0; i < mPer.info.size(); i++) {
    //    cout << mPer.info.at(i); //Error
    //}
    for (it = info.begin(); it != info.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it; // Error
    }

} else p.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);

}
```

It's obvious that operator overloading `operator<<` in `cout` is the problem. I have looked at several problems related to this, but no one helped me out. If someone can provide a concrete example on how to solve it, it would be very appreciated. *(Please do not talk in general about it, I am new to C++ and I have spent three days on it searching for solution.)*

Comment: @Baum mit Augen, This question was asked on 16 March 2013, and the you said it already has an answer (asked on 23 March 2014). Instead of marking the other question duplicate, you marked this one. Could not understand your logic.

Comment: When cleaning up old, common questions, the time of asking is no longer the main criterion. Instead, the usefulness of the Q/A is key. I chose the other one over this one because it has an actual MCVE, so the answer is more succinct as they need not come up with an example class body first. I feel like that's easier to read for future visitors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide an output stream operator for `PersonInfo`. Something like this:

```
struct PersonInfo
{
  int age;
  std::string name;
};

#include <iostream>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const PersonInfo& p)
{
  return o << p.name << " " << p.age;
}
```

This operator allows expressions of the type `A << B`, where `A` is an `std::ostream` instance (of which `std::cout` is one) and `B` is a `PersonInfo` instance.

This allows you do do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
  PersonInfo p = ....;
  std::cout << p << std::endl; // prints name and age to stdout

  // std::ofstream is also an std::ostream, 
  // so we can write PersonInfos to a file
  std::ofstream person_file("persons.txt");
  person_file << p << std::endl;
}
```

which in turn allows you to print the de-referenced iterator.

Comment: How i can refer to std::ostream& oprator<<() inside the loop?

Comment: @Hesper you already do, here `cout << *it;`. That's what I was trying to explain in the part that talks about `A << B`.

Comment: But still i am getting the same error.

Comment: @Hesper then you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I am posting my code here http://jsfiddle.net/yZps8/

Comment: @Hesper you have to put the `ostream& operator<<` declaration *before* you use it, i.e. before the definition of `void identify()`.

Comment: Yes, Now the error has gone, but the values are not displaying.

Comment: @Hesper well, your `info` vector is empty, so there's nothing to print.

Comment: Now its completely solved. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `*it` is an L-value of type `PersonInfo`. The compiler is complaining that there is no `operator<<` which takes a right-hand side argument of type `PersonInfo`.

For the code to work, you need to provide such an operator, for example like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &str, const PersonInfo &p)
{
  str << "Name: " << p.name << "\nAge: " << p.age << '\n';
  return str;
}
```

The exact implementation of the operator depends on your needs for representing the class in output, of course.

Comment: I created it, but the error is same. No match for operator<<

Comment: @Hesper Is the operator declaration visible from the function which calls it?

Comment: Can you look at this code? http://jsfiddle.net/yZps8/

Comment: @Hesper C++ is parsed top-to-bottom. This means the operator must be visible before it's used. Move its definition above the definition of `identify()`.

Comment: Now the error has gone :) but values are not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

What it's telling you is that there isn't a known wway to cout (console output) the contents of *it.

`it` is an iterator - think of this like a pointer in a list

the list is `info` so *it is current item in the `info`, which is a list of `PersonInfo` items.

So `cout << *it;` says output to the console the `PersonInfo` that it is currently referencing.

But the error message is telling you that the compiler doens't know how PersonInfo should be rendered to the console.

What you need to do is create an operator called `<<` that takes an object that `cout` is (`ostream`) and a `PersonInfo` object and then writes the various bits of the `PersonInfo` to `cout`.

Comment: I created the std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const PersonInfo& p) and implemented it. But, i am still getting the same error.