# c++ print a vector that contain a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am a c++ beginner. Could anybody tell me how to get the vector named mailVector printed. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct eMailMsg {
string to; // i.e. "professor@stanford.edu"
string from; // i.e. "student@stanford.edu"
string message; // body of message
string subject; // i.e. "CS106 Rocks!"
int date; // date email was sent
int time; // time email was sent
};

int main(){
    vector <eMailMsg> mailVector;
    eMailMsg professor={"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message","CS106 Rocks",4,16};
    mailVector.push_back(professor);
    for( std::vector<eMailMsg>::const_iterator i = mailVector.begin(); i != mailVector.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

the corresponding error is Error    1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const eMailMsg' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

updated ver1
:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
struct eMailMsg {
string to; // i.e. "professor@stanford.edu"
string from; // i.e. "student@stanford.edu"
string message; // body of message
string subject; // i.e. "CS106 Rocks!"
int date; // date email was sent
int time; // time email was sent
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const eMailMsg& rightOp)
    {
   os << rightOp.to << " " << rightOp.from << "etc ...";//error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

   return os;
   // We're writing std::string here and C++ can do that
}

int main(){
    vector <eMailMsg> mailVector;
    eMailMsg professor={"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message","CS106 Rocks",4,16};
    mailVector.push_back(professor);

    for( std::vector<eMailMsg>::const_iterator i = mailVector.begin(); i != mailVector.end(); ++i)
std::cout << *i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to overload `operator<<` for `eMailMsg` type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No match for 'operator<<' in std::cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449508/no-match-for-operator-in-stdcout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to print `eMailMsg` type. C++ doesn't know how to do that and you need to tell it.

Overload the `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const eMailMsg& rightOp)` in order to teach it.

You can do something like:

```
... {
   os << rightOp.to << " " << rightOp.from << "etc ...";
   return os;
   // We're writing std::string here and C++ can do that
}
```

Comment: @BenSeedangie What are you trying to tell us?

Comment: @BenSeedangie Ehhh, that overload (the operator<< thing) is basically a function, define it like one, do not insert it into main

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Yeah, you got me. Haha. but how could I use this function in main?? just `cout<<mailVector.to<<endl`??

Comment: just `cout << *t` in your case, the "<<" will deduce the type being passed in as `eMailMsg` and it will magically call `operator<<(ostream, eMailMsg)` which it was looking for but couldn't find originally, now it's there

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth OK. I know what you are saying. Thank you so much. However, there is an error at `os<<rightOp.to` please see my updated code.Error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: You need to add `#include <string>` with the rest of your includes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct eMailMsg {
string to; // i.e. "professor@stanford.edu"
string from; // i.e. "student@stanford.edu"
string message; // body of message
string subject; // i.e. "CS106 Rocks!"
int date; // date email was sent
int time; // time email was sent

    operator char const * () const
    {
        return  to.c_str();
    }

};

int main(){
    vector <eMailMsg> mailVector;
    eMailMsg professor={"professor@stanford.edu","student@stanford.edu","body of message","CS106 Rocks",4,16};
    mailVector.push_back(professor);
    for( std::vector<eMailMsg>::const_iterator i = mailVector.begin(); i != mailVector.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Notice the cast operator method formats the struct and the c++ compiler decides to use that operator to cast to "char *" as that's a valid argument type for the "<<" operator of the outstream.